# Growth Increase by type in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, that I wish to calculate the growth increase by the type:

```
location   size     type     date

ny         5        hello    10/01/2020
ny         7        ai       10/02/2020
ny         8        ai       10/03/2020
ny         6        hello    10/04/2020
ca         15       cool     10/05/2020
ca         10       name     10/06/2020
ca         5        name     10/07/2020
ca         16       cool     10/08/2020
```

Desired output

```
location  type    increase   percent_increase     start_date    end_date

ca        cool    1           6.67%               10/05/2020    10/08/2020
ca        name    -5         -50%                 10/6/2020     10/7/2020
ny        hello   1           20%                 10/01/2020    10/4/2020
ny        ai      1           14.28%              10/2/2020     10/3/2020
```

This is what I am doing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])                                                 


df1= df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='7D')).sum()                                    

df.groupby("type")["location"].()

df1['percent_increase'] = df1['Value'].pct_change().mul(100)                                                           
df1['increase'] = df1['Value'].diff()
```

I am not getting my desired output. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: why is `ai` `20%` increase? is the increase by `type` but the percentage calculation by `location` groups?

Comment: HI @Ehsan let me update - it should be 14.28%

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
df.groupby('type')['size'].agg(lambda x:(x.iloc[-1]/x.iloc[0]-1)*100)
```

Of course, you can add the rest of your desired columns to this.

output for your example:

```
ai       14.285714
cool      6.666667
hello    20.000000
name    -50.000000
```

Comment: yes @Ehsan, I believe this is what I am looking for! Thanks. Is there a w to include the raw value, and date could? df['ValueDiff'] = df['Size'].diff()??

Comment: @Lynnette `df.groupby('type')['size'].agg(lambda x:x.iloc[-1]-x.iloc[0])`? Please feel free to accept the answer if it resolves the issue.

Comment: Oh I see-  you are revealing it by index - let me see. The date will not be included though right? I will try this now

Comment: @Lynnette I see, you want a separate start date and end date? like `df1['startdate']= df.groupby('type')['date'].min()` and `df1['enddate']= df.groupby('type')['date'].max()`?

Comment: Hi @Ehsan, this is my desired goal that I am researching to incorporate, as I wish to create a scatter plot using Plotly

Comment: @Lynnette I just edited my comment to add dates too assuming the dates are sorted. if they are not sorted, simply use `iloc` to select the start and end date. Please check it again to see if it resolves the issue. Thank you.